# How can I see a reply to my comment on a deleted question?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-questions

I recently discovered that I have gotten a reply to one of my comments. However, the question that I commented on is deleted, so I can no longer see any of the comments on the question (including the reply to my comment).

How can I see the reply to my comment?

Answer (score 6):

There is no regular way to do that, sorry.

Once you have 10k reputation you'll be able to see deleted posts and this won't be an issue, but before then you won't be able to see replies like this.

However, poking into your comment history, the comment you were notified about was bringing to your attention our policy of not answering in comments: [Should users refrain from answers (or partial answers) in comments?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments). Naturally we ask you abide by that policy. There's no serious harm here though and you're not in trouble.