# What should comments be used for?

Tags: discussion, comments

I was in the process of drafting a minor frame challenge in a comment, and found myself thinking 'is this an appropriate use of comments?'

I hit up the meta hoping to find some general guidance on how comments should be used, but I haven't been able to find anything.

All the guidance around comments that I've received is framed negatively:

- Don't use comments for extended discussion
- Don't use comments for partial answers

Is there a simple, positive framing of what comments *should* be used for, rather than what they should not?

Comment: Related, on that second bullet: [Should users refrain from answers (or partial answers) in comments?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/52137)

Comment: Related from our site [meta-tag:faq]: [Why are site comments being deleted?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/why-are-site-comments-being-deleted)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I've found the answer to my own question in [the Help center's guidance on comments](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

### When should I comment?

You should submit a comment if you want to:

- Request clarification from the author;
- Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
- Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

Comment: Does rpg.so always inherit guidance/best practice from SO, except in the case of exceptions? That's the assumption behind this answer.

Comment: That's the built-in guidance for the comment privilege. You'll find the exact same on https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment. Exactly how close each site cares about that guidance will vary (different needs and cultures etc.). RPG takes a stong preference that solutions to the problem should go in answers, not comments

Comment: There are definitely some Stacks that allow more discussion within the comments. This has never been one of them.